# XCTest UI Testing - Drag and drop

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to drag an Image to particular layout in my app, I'm able to tap an image but unable to move across drop zone. and tried following solutions:

### **1**

```
let startCoord = XCUIApplication().cells.element(boundBy: 0).coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.01));
let endCoord = startCoord.withOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -900));
startCoord.press(forDuration: 0.25, thenDragTo: endCoord)
```

### **2**

```
let fromCoordinate = XCUIApplication().coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:CGVector(dx: 5, dy:10))
let toCoordinate = XCUIApplication().coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:CGVector(dx: 5, dy: 20))
fromCoordinate.press(forDuration: 5, thenDragTo: toCoordinate)
Locating through coordinates.
```

But still I'm not able to figure out the solution.

Does anyone know how to perform drag & drop correctly in Xcode 8.1?

Comment: Can you print the from/to coordinate x and y values for methods 1 and 2, and post them?

Comment: `coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:)` works in multiples of the element's frame size, so this is dragging between two points *way* off the application's window (5 window-widths right, and 10 window-heights down). (I discovered this the hard way trying to adapt this code.) [Docs link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500960-coordinate)

Answer (score 0):

first look at the function specification:

```
 public func pressForDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, thenDragToElement otherElement: XCUIElement)
```

It's clear that you must have to use an XCUIElement as "thenDragTo" parameter.

You are passing XCUICoordinate as parameter which is not valid.

Try to take the XCUIElement of the image, than take the XCUIElement where you want to drag and than use the function. A simple example is given below:

```
let firstImage = app.images.elementBoundByIndex(0)
let secondImage = app.images.elementBoundByIndex(1)
firstImage.pressForDuration(forDuration: 5, thenDragTo: secondImage)
//this will drag the first image to the second image location.
```

hope this help you and let me know what happens.

Comment: The function being used in the question is this one, which takes a coordinate: https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuicoordinate/1615003-press